# iOS Google Maps Transit Data

Tags: iphone, ios, google-maps, gtfs

Is it possible to use google maps transit data to show a publich transit route inside your application rather than sending a user to google maps app?
I see that google maps on iphone does it well for switzerland (region i am interested in).

Check http://code.google.com/intl/en/apis/maps/documentation/directions/#TravelModes 
driving, walking and bicycling are there, but it seems like transit is not available.

Anybody got an idea or workaround?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there isn't. Google licenses the data from transit agencies, not many of which licenses the data for use in the API. Some agencies publish their data in [Google Transit Feed Spec](https://developers.google.com/transit/gtfs/reference). There's a list of [those agencies](http://code.google.com/p/googletransitdatafeed/wiki/PublicFeeds), you could pull the data from the provider and parse it out yourself, but that's not available for everyone.

Answer (score 0):

See the [Transitland open data platform](https://www.transit.land) for a wide range of APIs for querying across all the feeds provided by transit agencies. Best places to start is the overview of the various APIs at https://www.transit.land/documentation/